# Regular expression for specific number of digits

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write a regular expression in C# that inputs only a specific number of only numbers.

Like writing a regular expression to validate 5 digits number like so "12345"

Comment: Please show us your own attempt. Stackoverflow is not here to do your work for you, but to help you with your own efforts when you're stuck.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the following regex with [`Regex.IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s19z3syh.aspx) method

```
^[0-9]{5}$
```

`^` and `$` will anchors the match to the beginning and the end of the string (respectively) to prevent a match to be found in the middle of a long string, such as `1234567890` or `abcd12345efgh`.

`[0-9]` indicates a character class that specifies a range of characters from `0` to `9`. The range is defined by the Unicode code range that starts and ends with the specified characters. The `{5}` followed behind is a *quantifier* indicating to repeat the `[0-9]` 5 times.

Note that the solution of `^\d{5}$` is only equivalent to the above solution, when [`RegexOptions.ECMAScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) is specified, otherwise, [it will be equivalent to `\p{Nd}`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#DigitCharacter), which matches any Unicode digits - here is [the list of all characters in `Nd` category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm). You should always check the documentation of the language you are using as to what the shorthand character classes actually matches.

I strongly suggest that you read through the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx). You can use other resources, such as http://www.regular-expressions.info/, but **always** check back on the documentation of the language that you are using.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the number of repetitions in braces as in:

```
\d{5}
```

If you want your whole input match a pattern enclose them in `^` and `$`:

```
^\d{5}$
```

Comment: And it will not just match `0-9` digits. It will also match other Unicode digits

Comment: @m.buettner No it matches only 5 digits. More digits may be returned in another match. However if OP intends to make sure the **whole** input consists of 5 digits he can use `^` and `$` that I reflected in my updated answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh OP is not specific to what kind of numbers he want to match.

Comment: It is important to notify such thing to the reader. It is not a consistent behavior in regex flavours.

Answer (score 0):

This expression should pass

```
\d{5}[^\d]+
```