# MVC5 attribute routing regular expression not producing desired result

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have used two regular expressions, one to limit the first parameter(year) to 4 digits and the second(month) to limit the second parameter to 2 digits.

```
[Route("movies/released/{year:regex(\\d{4})}/{month:regex(\\d{2}):range(1, 12)}")]
public ActionResult ByReleaseDate(int year, int month)
{
    return Content($"{year}/{month}");
}
```

This partially works, when I navigate to **/movies/released/2017/13** I am shown a 404.

But when I navigate to **/movies/released/200017/03** a 404 is not produced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex for year matches 4 digits anywhere but doesn't require it to be only 4 digits. You should use

```
{year:regex(^\\d{4}$)}
```

`^` and `$` mark the start and the end of the string. Also see: [Regular expression for specific number of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373895/regular-expression-for-specific-number-of-digits)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old and has already but answered but I thought sharing might help the visitors.
I was watching ASP .Net MVC5 tutorial by Mosh [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Voso411Vs) and found that he has mentioned the correction in Attribute Routing Section. Following worked for me.

```
[Route("movies/released/{year}/{month:regex(\\d{2}):range(1, 12)}")]
```

Comment: I am watching the same tutorial but this isn't working for me

Answer (score 1):

use {{2}} instead of {2}

In your case this will work `[Route("movies/released/{year}/{month:regex(\\d{{2}}):range(1, 12)}")]`

**explanation:** In a route parameter, '{' and '}' must be escaped with '{{' and '}}'.